# Storing values of entire list in the same csv row

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of lists something like the following

```
list = [[12,21][32,42],[55,67]]
```

All I want is to store the values of the list in a single row of a CSV file like shown below.

```
 | row-no | 12 | 21 | 32 | 42 | 55 | 67 |
```

Each value is kept in a different column of the CSV file. The size of the list can also vary in different rows of the CSV file.

Here is what I have done till now:

```
with open(somefile, 'w') as csvfile:
    InfoWrite = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    InfoWrite.writerow(['row-no','A','B','C','D','E','F'])

    len_list = len(list)
        if(len_list > 0):
            for j in range(len_list):
                InfoWrite.writerow([row-no,list[j][0],list[j][1]])
```

And it gives out the following:

```
| row-no | 12 | 21 |
| row-no | 32 | 42 |
| row-no | 55 | 67 |
```

I would like to achieve output similar to what is shown above. Any help and suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the list of lists with something like this:

```py
matrix = [[12,21], [32,42],[55,67]]
flatten_matrix = [val for sublist in matrix for val in sublist]
print(flatten_matrix)

>>> [12, 21, 32, 42, 55, 67]
```

And then write it to the `csv` with this:

```py
with open(somefile, 'w') as csvfile:
    InfoWrite = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    row_no = 'row-no'
    InfoWrite.writerow([row_no,'A','B','C','D','E','F'])
    InfoWrite.writerow([row_no] + flatten_matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *flatten* your list first. One of methods is as follows

```
import itertools
lst = [[12,21],[32,42],[55,67]]
lst = list(itertools.chain(*lst))
# now lst is [12, 21, 32, 42, 55, 67]
```

As side note: do not use built-in function as variable names - you will be unable to use these functions.

Answer (score 0):

This code is written in JavaScript

```
worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: false }, function (row, rowNumber) {

                var insideArray = [];
                row.eachCell({ includeEmpty: false }, function (cell, colNumber) {
                        insideArray[colNumber-1] = cell.value;
                });
               data = data[row]
```

It is not exact solution but can relate to it

Answer (score 0):

First you have to flatten your input list:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
import csv

my_list = [[12,21],[32,42],[55,67]]
flat = reduce(add, my_list) 
# this will give you [12, 21, 32, 42, 55, 67]

with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    InfoWrite = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    InfoWrite.writerow(['row-no','A','B','C','D','E','F'])
    InfoWrite.writerow(['row-no', *flat])
```